# How can I use shell scripting to iterate an argument that I can use in a python function like DoublePendulum2.py?

Tags: shell

Basically I want shell scripting to run something like this:

```
time python DoublePendulum.py 1 1 1
time python DoublePendulum.py 1 2 1
time python DoublePendulum.py 1 4 1
time python DoublePendulum.py 1 8 1
time python DoublePendulum.py 1 16 1
```

(the program produces specially named png files as output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you'll want to set up some terminating condition for your loop:

```
increment=1
terminating=2056

while [[ "$increment" -lt "$terminating" ]]
do
    time python DoublePendulum.py 1 "$increment" 1
    increment=$((increment * 2))
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `increment`: The variable that increments itself by multiplying by 2 each time
- `terminating`: Variable to keep track of when to terminate your loop. (Alternatively, you can do it for how many times you want the loop to run by implementing a separate counter that increments by 1 each time.
- `while [[ "$increment" -lt "$terminating" ]]`: Run while terminating condition hasn't been reached.
- `time python DoublePendulum.py 1 "$increment" 1`: Substitute your increment in.
- `increment=$((increment * 2))`: Increase your increment.